# Magento : How to hide or remove "add to cart" button in Grouped products

Tags: magento-1.9, grouped-products

I Created grouped product . I alter the position of Grouped product. So how i can  remove

"ADD TO CART" button  in magento?

In which folder, which code i have to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your local.xml

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
    <remove name="product.info.addtocart" />
</PRODUCT_TYPE_grouped>
```

Didn't tested it, but then the block with the add to cart button should be removed for all grouped products

Answer (score 0):

use following lazy way

edit file in `[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
find this code <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
```

add following code

```
<?php 
if($_product->getTypeId() == 'grouped')
{
    ?>

   <style>
     .add-to-cart button.button{
         display:none !important;
     }
   </style>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: you are ultimate. Just awesome. thanks a lot , you saved my life. i need more help. I will be really happy, if you contact me on realworker99atgmaildotcom. Thanks again.

Comment: Style in the <body> tag is bad practice.

Comment: yes of course is bad, that's why i mentioned 'lazy way' ;-)

Comment: Thanks Fabian, Fabian answer is working fine, but i want to learn more. I don't have any idea in xml, Can you please tell me where i have to add your above code in local.xml file, means after which line..?